# Owl Carousel 2 for logo items not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I'm have trouble with a bootstrap template I have downloaded. The theme is "REVEAL". In the logo part, the slide should use infinite loop, but at the last logo it jumps directly and does not continue to the first one . Can anyone help?

Trying to make the loop as "TRUE".

```
<div class="owl-carousel clients-carousel">
    <img src="img/clients/client-1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-2.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-3.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-4.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-5.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-6.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-7.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/clients/client-8.png" alt="">
</div>


</script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".clients-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 2
      },
      768: {
        items: 4
      },
      900: {
        items: 6
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Deby, can you provide a JSFiddle or a CodePen link to show your code?

Comment: There is a typo problem where you're opening `<script>` tag. There is a backslash at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by @Flo, you've typo while opening the `<script>` tag. Also, from [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html):

> You don't need any special markup. All you need is to wrap your
>   divs(owl works with any type element a/img/span..) inside the
>   container element . **Class "owl-carousel" is
>   mandatory** to apply proper styles that come from owl.carousel.css file.
>   If you want the default nav controls like dots or buttons, you must
>   also include the "owl-theme" class on that same div.

Here's working example:

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-1.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-2.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-3.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-4.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-5.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Reveal/img/clients/client-6.png" alt="">
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-UhQQ4fxEeABh4JrcmAJ1+16id/1dnlOEVCFOxDef9Lw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha256-kksNxjDRxd/5+jGurZUJd1sdR2v+ClrCl3svESBaJqw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
      loop: true,
      autoplayTimeout:2000,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 2
        },
        768: {
          items: 4
        },
        900: {
          items: 6
        }
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**
The Bootstrap template, you're using, uses older version `2.3.2` of the Owl Carousel. I recommend updating to latest version.

It seems like, in older versions to make the infinite loop work properly, you need to set `checkVisibility` option, as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2261#issuecomment-375019318).
So, in addition to your other options, set:

`checkVisibility: true`

Comment: thank you all, I saw my mistake. Code works fine, but when I insert in my template I can't find the problems but Its still jumping. I don't know how to put the whole code(template) here in order to get your help. Maybe problem with jquery. This is the template online link (https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Reveal/) in CLIENT PART , check that and maybe you can understand what I'm talking about

Comment: I've updated the answer, for your specific use case. Let me know, if it works.

Comment: Owl Carousel updated to version 2.3.4. Its work fine. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it helped you.